# Joining more than 2 streams in Flink & applying CEP to more than 2 streams without joining them

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

**Question # 1** : I am working on a case scenario where we need to fuse data from multiple sensors [8 sensors for instance] and join them in a tree form. For example, joining [s1,s2,s3 s4] to form stream A and then [s5,s6,s7 and s8] to form Stream B and then perform CEP on stream A and B. How can I achieve this?

**Question # 2 :** Is it possible to perform CEP on multiple streams, means more than one stream ?. It is clearly mentioned in  [flink 1.3.2 API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/libs/cep.html#detecting-patterns) that pattern will be applied to one stream

```
DataStream<Event> input = ...
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = ...

PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(input, pattern);
```

If  pattern can not be applied on more than one stream, then how will Flink CEP work with the classic example of CEP which involves **smoke stream** and **temperature stream** to create an alert when there is **fire**.

- does joining both smoke and temp stream based on some key like
  the timestamp, is the only solution?
- Then how can Flink be applied to broad use cases of IOT which involves multiple sensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you are reading data from sensors, if the data arrives on different kafka topics, you can create 2 flink jobs .

Job 1 - Reads from sensor topics s1,s2,s3,s4 and creates a stream A and then another kafkaconsumer reads from s5,s6,s7,s8 and creates stream B. Then you push the data from these 2 streams on 2 intermediate topics -> streamA, streamB

Job 2 - Now job 2 reads from kafka topics streamA and streamB together and creates a single datastream.

> Keep in mind that when you do this, you should rely on event time of
>   your sensor data and not on ingestion time or processing time, for
>   getting accurate results.

After joining 2 streams, running CEP is not really difficult as you can see from this previous question - [Process multiple streams in Flink CEP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379070/is-it-possible-to-process-multiple-streams-in-apache-flink-cep/)